# Illegal string offset PHP 5.6

Tags: php, cakephp

We have an old version of CakePHP that we've moved to a new server running PHP 5.6 and we've started to recieve this error when adding a product to the basket:

> Warning (2): Illegal string offset 'AddBasketData'
>   [APP/controllers/personalisation_controller.php, line 848]

Here is line 848 within the file:

```
if (is_array($this->data['AddBasketData'])) {
    $personalisation_data['Personalise'] = $this->data['AddBasketData'];
}else {
        $personalisation_data['Personalise'] = array();
}
```

Could anyone shed any light on this, I think it's down to the specific PHP version we're running now but any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: What does `var_dump($this->data);` return ?

Comment: Hi roberto I get: string(4) "skip".

Comment: Then that's the problem, `$this->data` isn't an `array` but a `string`, thus you can't access the offset `AddBasketData`.

Comment: Yea ok so what i've done is !is_string($this->data) within the if statement.

Comment: That'd work, but there could also be the case where `$this->data` is an array but the offset `AddBasketData` doesn't exist or isn't an array (which is what you were testing at first). I'd use `if (is_array($this->data) && isset($this->data['AddBasketData']) && is_array($this->data['AddBasketData']))`.

Comment: And remember if in your `if` statement will be true `$personalisation_data['Personalise']` will be a `string` otherwise an empty `array`.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by @roberto06 in the comments to your question, the reason you're getting the error is because you're trying to treat a string value as an array.
The reason for that specific error message is because you can use the array-offset notation to fetch a single character from the string. Just like you'd do in C's string arrays. But this only support numerical indices, and not a string index as shown in the code you posted.

Now, the easy way to stop the error from occurring is to simply test the type of the data, and whether or not the given index actually exists.
Like so:

```
if (is_array ($this->data) && !empty ($this->data['AddBasketData'])) {
    $personalisation_data['Personalise'] = $this->data['AddBasketData'];
} else {
    $personalisation_data['Personalise'] = array();
}
```

However, seeing as you're not suddenly getting this error after update hints towards something else being the issue. Especially since the code you posted expects the value stored in the `Personalise` index to be an array. I'd trace where the `$this->data` member gets set, and changed, to see if you can find the underlying reason for why this apparent change in behavior. This might be the side-effect of a more nefarious subtle bug, after all.

Comment: That will still raise an offset warning, you have to test `is_array($this->data)` first.

Comment: @roberto06 Ah, thank you for letting me know: Copy-pasta error. Fixed the code example now. :)

Answer (score 0):

Transforming my comments into an answer :

The problem here seems to be that `$this->data` is a `string` and not an `array`.
You should test this first, then check if the offset `AddBasketData` exists, and finally if the offset `AddBasketData` is an `array` :

```
if (is_array($this->data) && isset($this->data['AddBasketData']) && is_array($this->data['AddBasketData'])) {
    $personalisation_data['Personalise'] = $this->data['AddBasketData'];
} else {
    $personalisation_data['Personalise'] = array();
}
```

Of course, that will only correct the symptoms (which is the raised warning), you might have some code debugging to do to find out why  `$this->data` is a `string` instead of an `array`.